# Custom Cordova Plugin for SystemWebView to intercept request and change headers

Tags: cordova, plugins, webview, interceptor

we are trying to build a cordova plugin for our ionic3 app which use a Custom WebView for Android (from KITKAT up) where we can intercept a http request.

The Android WebView is adding always an Origin header to a request, but we don't wan't to do this. A RESTFUL service we use don't support `origin file://` header
We are not sure if it works, but we try to overwrite the WebView and intercept the request to change headers.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

If the service only rejects file:// origins, an alternative could be run a small local webserver in the app and use that as your content url. You'd get a http://localhost origin instead. There's an [iOS-only example](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/local-webserver) that was created to get around some WKWebView limitations, but the same principle could be applied to Android as well.

Comment: This could be a solution, but I think it is a very heavy solution for that or not? To have up a local server to do a simple header change? But perhapse it is not so simple as I hoped. I opened a post in the ionic forum to discuss how to intercept an http request in webview https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/customizing-some-parts-of-android-sytem-webview/102342

Comment: Yeah it might be overkill. For ios it is helpful, since all the network requests for WKWebView are in another process so it is not possible to intercept them. For Android you should have other options.

Comment: Based on your ionic post, you may be able to use a plugin. That feature doesn't seem to be well documented but there is some info here. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8702 It seems like you create a plugin that implements remapUri to redirect requests to your plugin and handleOpenForRead to resolve the request that is directed to your plugin.

Comment: A third option could be to implement a custom pluggable webview. That might give you most flexibility.

Comment: But do you think we can handler remove origin header with handleOpenForRead? Can you help on custom pluggable webview?